# Vectorized example of the math.atan2() function in python

Tags: python, numpy, math, vectorization, trigonometry

let us say I have a numpy matrix `A` that is of size `Nx2`. What I am doing, is computing the 4-quadrant inverse tangent of the first column, and the second column, as so:

```
import math
for i in xrange(A.shape[0]):
  phase[i] = math.atan2(A[i,0], A[i,1])
```

I would however like to do this in a vectorized manner. How can I do that? The math.atan2() function does not seem to support vectorization.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It looks to me like it should just be:

```
import numpy as np
phase = np.arctan2(A[:, 0], A[:, 1])
```

Or possibly (if `phase` is a different length than `A` for some odd reason):

```
phase[:len(A)] = np.arctan2(A[:, 0], A[:, 1])
```

In other words, don't use `math.atan2`, use `numpy.arctan2` since numpy functions are generally vectorized versions of their `math` counterparts.

Comment: Dont know how I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way for me to make it give results where the angles are from 0 to 360?

Comment: Check out [`np.rad2deg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rad2deg.html#numpy.rad2deg).  And don't forget to accept the answer from @mgilson (click the check)